# Decode string containing both hexidecimal and ASCII into decimal

Tags: python, hex, ascii, decode

I have a long string containing both hexadecimal and ASCII characters and need to convert the string into a list of individual decimal (integers) values.

All of the hexadecimal characters are contained within square brackets and I have figured out how to extract these and convert these into integers. This is shown in the code below:

```
# String from log file
log7 = ',[[0x8][0x1c][0x12][0x6][0xc][0x13][0xa6][0x1]a[0xc][0x9c][0x1][0xf4][0x0][0xa4][0x1][0xf7][0x1][0xa8][0x0],[0x4][0xfe][0x0][0x7][0x0][0x7][0x2][0xf0][0x7]L[0x2]u[0x0][0xa5][0x0][0xe3][0x0][0xb9][0x0]@[0x4][0xb][0x1][0x4][0x0][0x6][0x2][0x14][0x8]m[0x2]v[0x0][0xb3][0x0][0xbb][0x0][0xc5][0x0][0xa2][0xff][0x12][0x1][0x6][0x0]'

# Extract all text in square brackets and put into a list
extract = re.findall(r"\[([A-Za-z0-9_]+)\]", log7)

# Convert all hexidecimal values in list to decimal
convert = [int(x, 16) for x in extract]

# [8, 28, 18, 6, 12, 19, 166, 1, 12, 156, 1, 244, 0, 164, 1, 247, 1, 168, 0, 4, 254, 0, 7, 0, 7, 2, 240, 7, 2, 0, 165, 0, 227, 0, 185, 0, 4, 11, 1, 4, 0, 6, 2, 20, 8, 2, 0, 179, 0, 187, 0, 197, 0, 162, 255, 18, 1, 6, 0]
```

However, the above code does not include the ASCII characters and what I really need to do, is to convert the mix of hex and ASCII to decimals in the order they occur in the string.

I know that I can convert the individual ASCII code to decimal using:

```
converted_ascii = [ord(x) for x in ascii_list]
```

The outcome I am need is, where bold are the missing ASCII characters - from the first lot of code above:

**44**, **91**, 8, 28, 18, 6, 12, 19, 166, 1, **97** ,12, 156, 1, 244, 0, 164, 1, 247, 1, 168, 0, **44**, 4, 254, 0, 7, 0, 7, 2, 240, 7, **76**, 2, **117**, 0, 165, 0, 227, 0, 185, 0, **64**, 4, 11, 1, 4, 0, 6, 2, 20, 8, **109**, 2, **118**, 0, 179, 0, 187, 0, 197, 0, 162, 255, 18, 1, 6, 0

Please, can someone offer some advice on how to get through this next step?

Comment: how about `r"(\[[A-Za-z0-9_]+\]|\w)"` to split it? And how you can use loop - if you get string with `[ ]` then you have hex which needs `int()` , otherwise it is char which needs `ord()`

Comment: `\w` doesn't capture `,` or `[`, the two first ascii chars

Answer (score 1):

I would do

```py
extract = re.findall(r"\[0x[0-9A-Za-z]+\]|.", log7)

convert = [ord(x) if len(x) == 1 else int(x[1:-1], 16) for x in extract]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `re` you can use the split function to get all those value as:

```py
r = re.split('\[|\]',log7[2:])
values = []
for i in r:
    if i:
        try:
            values.append(int(i, 16)) # Tries to convert hex into integer
        except ValueError: # if failed it is an assci value
            values.append(ord(i)) # convert it into integer
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the second ascii char: `ord('[')` => 91

Comment: @JoseKilo can simple manipulate the string at the start or strip it